# Java: NullpointerException when loading image-url from resources

Tags: java, image, url, nullpointerexception, resources

I am new to programming and I've stumbled upon a problem while trying to load an image-url from the resources-package in my project.

This is the filepath im trying to load from:
**./src/main/resources/minesweeper/foggedTile.png**

```
public Image setFoggedFrontImage() {
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    String path = classLoader.getResource("foggedTile.png").getPath();
    Image NewGameFrontImage = new Image(path);
    this.frontImage = NewGameFrontImage;
    return NewGameFrontImage;
    }
```

When I try to run this code I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.getPath()" 
because the return value of "java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(String)" is null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the complete path started after `resources`:

```
String path = classLoader.getResource("/minesweeper/foggedTile.png").getPath();
```

if you only add the file name of the image java looks into the same path as your class is located and it looks like the class is not in a package named minesweeper

Comment: Actually, your explanation is only halfway true. Using `Class.getResource` will _look_ into the same path when dealing with relative paths. `ClassLoader.getResource` on the other hand always uses the classpath (or that what is considered the classpath by the corresponding class loader).